# Move to lambda while using the variable in the same command

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, operator-precedence

Let us consider following structures designed to ruin the world.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct SkyNet {
    std::vector<int> terminators;

    SkyNet() = default;
    SkyNet(SkyNet&& that)
    {
        printf("Move construct\n");
        this->terminators = std::move(that.terminators);
    }
};

class Apocalypse {
public:
    template <typename Lambda>
    void run(Lambda lambda) {
        lambda();
    }
};

Apocalypse create_apocalypse(const SkyNet& net) {
    std::cout << "Create: " << net.terminators.size() << " terminators\n";
    return Apocalypse();
}
```

(Please excuse bad design of these structures and other flaws. It was created only to demonstrate specific problem.)

Then we have simple main:

```
int main()
{
    SkyNet net;
    net.terminators.push_back(10);

    create_apocalypse(net)
    .run([net = std::move(net)] {
        std::cout << "Lambda: " << net.terminators.size() << " terminators\n";
    });
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Move construct
Create: 0 terminators
Lambda: 1 terminators
```

That means argument of the `run` function will be created(evaluated?) before calling `create_apocalypse` function on which other events are chained. Is it correct? Is this a general rule that all of arguments of an expression (not only arguments of first function) are evaluated first and only then functions get called?

Comment: Order is unspecified, as for `f(foo(), bar())`.

Comment: I see. Are you aware of any reasons for that?

Comment: It might allow to use the best order for optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a lambda, you're creating an anonymous object. When you define the closure, you're defining its constructor and members.

So this is equivalent to something like:

```
crete_apocalypse(net).run(MyLambda{std::move(net)});
```

Which is semantically equivalent to something like

```
run(create_apocalypse(net), MyLambda{std::move(net)});
```

Since order of evaluation for function arguments is unspecified by the standard, the implementation is free to choose. In other words, it can either choose to go for `create_apocalypse(net)` first and do as you seemed to expect, or it can go the other way around (which it does in your case) and construct `MyLambda` first, thereby moving `net` so that once it gets to `create_apocalypse()`, it's already moved.

When it actually matters, you shouldn't rely on the behavior you get for your particular compiler. The way to avoid it and maintain correctness would be to write it like this:

```
auto a = create_apocalypse(net);
a.run([net = std::move(net)] { /* ... */ });
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/VRVY64880)</kbd>